# Bash script works locally but not on a server

Tags: linux, bash, server, slack

This Bash script is called from a SlackBot using a Python script that uses the paramiko library.  This works perfectly when I run the script locally from the bot.  It runs the application and then kills the process after the allotted time.  But when I run this same script on a server from the SlackBot, it doesn't kill the process.  Any suggestions??  The script name is "runslack.sh" which is what is called with the grep command below.

```
#!/bin/bash

slack-export-viewer -z "file.zip"

sleep 10

ps aux | grep runslack.sh | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill
```

Comment: Might I suggest `pkill runslack.sh`?

Comment: or replace `grep runslack.sh` with `grep ru[n]slack.sh`.

Comment: or `timeout 10 slack-export-viewer -z "file.zip"`

Comment: Replace `ps` and `grep` with `pgrep`.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this and let me know if this helps you

```
ps -ef | grep runslack.sh | grep -v grep  | awk '{print $2}' |xargs -i kill -9 {}
```

and i hope your user has sufficient permission to execute/kill this action on your server environment.